# How to sort position stages using default_group_by field selection of kanban view in Odoo 12

Tags: python, odoo-12

I define stages of kanban view by selection field,
like this:

```
state = fields.Selection([
    ('draft', 'Draft'),
    ('open', 'Open'),
    ('pending', 'Pending'),
    ('cancel', 'Cancelled'),
    ('done', 'Done')],
    'State',
    default='draft'
)
```

So I use default_group_by in **xml** to show this stages:

```
<kanban string="Kanban Sprint" default_group_by="state">
            <field name="name"/>
            <field name="state"/>
```

I want it sorts *Draft>Open>Pending>Cancelled>Done*.

But it sorts by **alphabet**: *Cancelled>Done>Draft>Open>Pending*.
[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpmhs.png)

So is there a way to sort them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use group_expand method to set the order:

```
state = fields.Selection([
    ('draft', 'Draft'),
    ('open', 'Open'),
    ('pending', 'Pending'),
    ('cancel', 'Cancelled'),
    ('done', 'Done')],
    'State',
    group_expand='_expand_groups',
    default='draft'
)

@api.model
def _expand_groups(self, states, domain, order):
    return ['draft', 'open', 'pending', 'cancel', 'done']
```

Comment: I got it! However I want which stage doesn't have item will be hidden, so use group_expand can't do that

Comment: for that your can override the read_group method